# Where to make the logic of the class?

Tags: c++, architecture, namespaces

I have a number I should be able to encode and decode. To do this, I have two classes. I had taken out of the calculation logic class mantissa and exponent in the namespace and want to make a transfer operations to other notations.

**asreal.h**

```
class ASNRealEncoder
{
private:
    std::vector<unsigned int> vectorMantissa_;
    std::vector<unsigned int> ascii_;

class ASNRealDecoder
{
private:
    std::vector<unsigned int> ASNReal_;
    std::vector<unsigned int> vectorMantissa_;
```

main.cpp

```
namespace fp_operations
{
}
main()
{
   ASNRealEncoder EnExample1(344.15, BIN, fp_operations::extractionData(344.1525, BIN));
}
```

But it does not look very attractive. Can cost the same to make classes in this namespace? How will correct \ beautiful \ pleasing to the eye?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you have one h-file and one cpp-file for every class you define. In the h-file you declare methods and membervariables and in the cpp-file you define (the logic) them.
Take a look at this link: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/89-class-code-and-header-files/ and scroll down to "Putting class definitions in a header file" to see an example.

In your case you should create asnRealEncoder.h and asnRealEncoder.cpp and asnRealDecoder.h and asnRealDecoder.cpp and

import asnRealEncoder.h and asnRealDecoder.h in you main.cpp